Place some or all of the White Chess pieces on a chessboard in such a way that none of them can legally move
Place some or all of the White Chess pieces on a standard chessboard in such a way that no piece can legally move.
If you use two bishops they must be on different colored squares.
No pawn can be on the first or eighth rank.
No pawn can be promoted.
No Black pieces are involved in this puzzle.

Attribution:  Douglas Hoylman

Here's a solution I created just now that uses every piece.

 
 The four pieces on c8-f8 (bishops, queen and king) can be swapped around and will still form a valid solution as long as the bishops are on opposite-coloured squares.

